# Is there a way to find the number at a certain position of the reduced echelon form given any matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a way to quickly calculate the number of the reduced echelon form of a matrix. Is there any?

Example:

> $A = $$
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>          1 & -1 & 3 &  8 \\
>         -4 &  2 & 1 & -8\\
>         -2 &  3 & 5 &  7 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $
>
> Let B be the reduced echelon form of
>
> What is the value of $B_{24}$?